# Color param which is get from Retrofit is not displayed in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, retrofit, android-view

I have a param in retrofit which is nothing but color, whose data in form of " #0DEAB5 ", I need to set it in my recycler view and to display the list of colors, for this I created an imageView and assigned my param to the imagView of XML, but the color is not viewed in recycler view.. so any solution that could be helpful please share...

Answer (score 1):

```
1.create circle Drawable


   <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval"
        >
    
        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp"/>
    </shape>

2.set drawable to view 

<View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"/>

3.onbind in reclyeradapter   
    

Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.circle); 
    mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        yourview.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
    } else {
        yourview.setBackground(mDrawable);
    }`
    
Here we don't want to use glide for transform the view to circle and change the alpha in Color.parseColor("#000000")
```

Comment: I used to set drawable instead of color which is in circle format, and then i used glide to set color as image, is it possible to do with view ? , can u pls say how?

Comment: check answer. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String color = "#FF" + yourColorString.replace("#",""); // if you get a color of only 6 digits and need an alpha

String color = "#0DEAB5"; // if you don't care about the alpha
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(color));
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Also note that yourImageView must have a set size, because colorDrawable haven't.